# How to create a new locale for dojo calendar?

Tags: javascript, ant, dojo

I am new to dojo.I am trying to add new language support to the dojo calendar widget.
From their website i was able to understand that they only provide a subset of locales. In order to add locales for additional languages you have to do it yourself by running the ant on build.xml in the util folder.

After doing an ant clean and building it,my build ran successfully but no new locales were added.

Could anyone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

How can I add additional language support to the dojo's calendar widget?